# what happens to stdout from an executable when running as systemd service

Tags: systemd

I'm setting up my app to run as systemd service for testing, i.e the app will change and it's currently generating output to stdout.

Is this an issue?
Can I view the output in real-time if I need to?
I'm not sure I'd like to log the output because if run for a long time may waste disk space. but if I do want to log output from the process how can I do that either while it's running or between systemctl stop/restart?

Thanks
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I've found what I was looking for after figuring out what to search:

Systemd provides several ways to view or collect output from the executing service unit(s):

- journalctl tool, which requires no beforehand preparation.  It displays the output in several forms a page at a time, until cancelled.
  Output can be filtered for a specific service unit.
- rsyslog tool must be installed and relies on making changes to the service unit file and a rsyslog.d config file.  rsyslog manages the stdout and stderr of the service. Any changes to rsyslog specific service will require a service unit reload.
- newer versions of systemd (version 240 or newer) offer a third way to  redirect our service's stdout and stderr without invoking the services of a syslog deamon

[This explain further and provides examples](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/redirect-systemd-output-to-file)
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/redirect-systemd-output-to-file